# Append a column to Data Frame in Apache Spark 1.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Is it possible and what would be the most efficient neat method to add a column to Data Frame?

More specifically, column may serve as Row IDs for the existing Data Frame.

In a simplified case, reading from file and not tokenizing it, I can think of something as below (in Scala), but it completes with errors (at line 3), and anyways doesn't look like the best route possible:

```
var dataDF = sc.textFile("path/file").toDF() 
val rowDF = sc.parallelize(1 to DataDF.count().toInt).toDF("ID") 
dataDF = dataDF.withColumn("ID", rowDF("ID"))
```

Comment: What are the errors? That seems like the right method in the API.

Comment: @Chet, `withColumn` is supposed to work with the same dataframe - i.e. you can do something like `dataDF = dataDF.withColumn("ID", dataDF("ID").map(...))` with the column of `this` dataframe only, not with others

Comment: @OlegShirokikh ah. huh. it'd be nice if that restriction were documented. Interesting problem then. the only mechanism I can see from the API otherwise would be to use a `join`. Not a bad candidate to suggest for an API enhancement.

Comment: @Chet - right, it's one of the core funcitonalities for any data frame. For example, they have some built-in functionality to update the schema of Parquet files. Obviously, it's very expensive operation in a distributed environement, but anyways IMO it should be there

Comment: Did you try to use an UDF? (something like ``sqlContext.udf().register("...``

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted the question and it seems that some other people would like to get an answer as well. Below is what I found.

So the original task was to append a column with row identificators (basically, a sequence `1 to numRows`) to any given data frame, so the rows order/presence can be tracked (e.g. when you sample). This can be achieved by something along these lines:

```
sqlContext.textFile(file).
zipWithIndex().
map(case(d, i)=>i.toString + delimiter + d).
map(_.split(delimiter)).
map(s=>Row.fromSeq(s.toSeq))
```

**Regarding the general case of appending any column to any data frame:**

The "closest" to this functionality in Spark API are `withColumn` and `withColumnRenamed`. According to [Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), the former *Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column*. In my opinion, this is a bit confusing and incomplete definition. Both of these functions can operate on `this` data frame only, i.e. given two data frames `df1` and `df2` with column `col`:

```
val df = df1.withColumn("newCol", df1("col") + 1) // -- OK
val df = df1.withColumn("newCol", df2("col") + 1) // -- FAIL
```

So unless you can manage to transform a column in an existing dataframe to the shape you need, you can't use `withColumn` or `withColumnRenamed` for appending arbitrary columns (standalone or other data frames).

As it was commented above, the workaround solution may be to use a `join` - this would be pretty messy, although possible - attaching the unique keys like above with `zipWithIndex` to both data frames or columns might work. Although efficiency is ...

It's clear that appending a column to the data frame is not an easy functionality for distributed environment and there may not be very efficient, neat method for that at all. But I think that it's still very important to have this core functionality available, even with performance warnings.

Comment: There is some recent initiative to support row_number function (among others) - [SPARK-7712](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7712)

The JIRA ticket does not mention it explicitly, so you might want to look into the [related pull-request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6278/files#diff-5dade93a3cce85de2ceeab02bd9d4ff6R531)

Comment: Good answer! The appending column functionality could be optimized if Spark known that I am joining on the *sorted* key. That would be a big performance boosting.

Comment: If you are looking to append an id column you should look at the function monotonically_increasing_id() which can be used inside of withColumn.

Comment: monotonically_increasing_id() has deep fragility issues and you must be very careful if you use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe/35706321

Answer (score 31):

not sure if it works in spark 1.3 but in spark 1.5 I use withColumn:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


df.withColumn("newName",lit("newValue"))
```

I use this when I need to use a value that is not related to existing columns of the dataframe

This is similar to @NehaM's answer but simpler

Answer (score 6):

I took help from above answer. However, I find it incomplete if we want to change a `DataFrame` and current APIs are little different in `Spark 1.6`. 
`zipWithIndex()` returns a `Tuple` of `(Row, Long)` which contains each row and corresponding index. We can use it to create new `Row` according to our need.

```
val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
             .map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq(indexedRow._2.toString +: indexedRow._1.toSeq))
val newstructure = StructType(Seq(StructField("Row number", StringType, true)).++(df.schema.fields))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, newstructure ).show
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#row_number()) with [Window function](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) as below to get the distinct id for each rows in a dataframe.

```
df.withColumn("ID", row_number() over Window.orderBy("any column name in the dataframe"))
```

You can also use `monotonically_increasing_id` for the same as

```
df.withColumn("ID", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

And there are some [other ways](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/generate-unique-ids-for-each-rows-in-a-spark-dataframe/) too.