# Append Column to Row in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` which I want to extend by a new column. Creating a new `DateFrame` from `Row`s is explained [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

My current strategy is to construct new `Row`s with the RowFactory from the `Row`s that are passed into my map invoked by `DataFrame.javaRDD().map(...)` but I fear that this might create unnecessary costs.

So I wonder if instead of creating new `Row`s, can I just extend the existing `Row`s by appending the new field. The `Row` interface doesn't seem to allow that.

[code of Row](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala)

Comment: I think you cant  modify as it is immutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sachin Janani mentions in a comment you cannot modify a Row (it's immutable), but you *can* append a column to a `DataFrame` using the `withColumn`-function. The code below will for instance add a column with the length of the strings found in column "text":

```
val stringLength = udf[Int, String](s => s.length)
val df2 = df1.withColumn("text_length", stringLength(df1("text")))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to what I want but my udf would be very complicated (counting certain word occurrences in another column's text). I'll definitely keep [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#withColumn%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column%29) in mind. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483498/append-a-column-to-data-frame-in-apache-spark-1-3) is related to this.