# How do I add an persistent column of row ids to Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

This question is not new, however I am finding surprising behavior in Spark. I need to add a column of row IDs to a DataFrame. I used the DataFrame method monotonically_increasing_id() and It does give me an additional col of uniques row IDs (that are NOT consecutive by the way, but are unique).

The problem I'm having is that when I filter the DataFrame the row Ids in the resulting DataFrame are re-assigned. The two DataFrames are shown below.

- the first one is the initial DataFrame with row IDs added as follows:

  ```
  df.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
  ```
- the second DataFrame is the one obtained after filtering on the col P via `df.filter(col("P"))`.

The problem is illustrated by the rowId for custId 169, which was 5 in the initial DataFrame, but after filtering that rowId (5) was re-assigned to custmId 773 when custId 169 was filtered out! I don't know why this is the default behavior.

I would want the `rowIds` to be "sticky"; if I remove rows from the DataFrame I do not want their IDs "re-used", I want them gone too along with their rows. Is it possible to do that? I don't see any flags to request this behavior from `monotonically_increasing_id` method.

```
+---------+--------------------+-------+
| custId  |    features|    P  |rowId|
+---------+--------------------+-------+
|806      |[50,5074,...|   true|    0|
|832      |[45,120,1...|   true|    1|
|216      |[6691,272...|   true|    2|
|926      |[120,1788...|   true|    3|
|875      |[54,120,1...|   true|    4|
|169      |[19406,21...|  false|    5|

after filtering on P:
+---------+--------------------+-------+
|   custId|    features|    P  |rowId|
+---------+--------------------+-------+
|      806|[50,5074,...|   true|    0|
|      832|[45,120,1...|   true|    1|
|      216|[6691,272...|   true|    2|
|      926|[120,1788...|   true|    3|
|      875|[54,120,1...|   true|    4|
|      773|[3136,317...|   true|    5|
```

Comment: Could you share your full code for generating the two example DataFrames? For what it's worth, this is likely due to the SQL query optimization that takes place in which "independent" map stages may be rearranged.

Comment: Hamel, there's really no other transformations or action than I posted. The data frames shown are the result of df.show(). You can very easily recreate this behavior, create a data frame and add a row ID column as above, then add a random boolean column to it. Then filter on that column and see how the row IDs you get from monotonically increasing are "re-used" as I describe.

Comment: @Kai I would actually add that the simplest way to reproduce it is to use only a single partition.

Comment: Issue on the Spark tracker for this: [SPARK-14241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14241)

Comment: Thank you Nick for taking this up.

Comment: This behavior is getting fixed in Spark 2.1.0. See [SPARK-14393](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14393) and the linked PRs.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for updating the thread.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Spark 2.0**

- This is issue has been resolved in Spark 2.0 with [SPARK-14241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14241).
- Another similar issue has been resolved in Spark 2.1 with [SPARK-14393](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14393)

**Spark 1.x**

Problem you experience is rather subtle but can be reduced to a simple fact `monotonically_increasing_id` is an extremely ugly function. It is clearly not pure and its value depends on something that is completely out your control.

It doesn't take any parameters so from an optimizer perspective it doesn't matter when it is called and can be pushed after all other operations. Hence the behavior you see.

If you take look at the code you'll find out this is explicitly marked by extending `MonotonicallyIncreasingID` expression with `Nondeterministic`.

<s>I don't think there is any elegant solution but one way you can handle this is to add an artificial dependency on the filtered value. For example with an UDF like this:</s>

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

bound = udf(lambda _, v: v, LongType()) 

(df
  .withColumn("rn", monotonically_increasing_id())
  # Due to nondeterministic behavior it has to be a separate step
  .withColumn("rn", bound("P", "rn"))  
  .where("P"))
```

In general it could be cleaner to add indices using `zipWithIndex` on a `RDD` and then convert it back to a `DataFrame`.

---

* Workaround shown above is no longer a valid solution (nor required) in Spark 2.x where Python UDFs are subject of the execution plan optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't reproduce this. I'm using Spark 2.0 though so maybe the behaviour has changed, or I am not doing the same thing as you.

```
val df = Seq(("one", 1,true),("two", 2,false),("three", 3,true),("four", 4,true))
.toDF("name", "value","flag")
.withColumn("rowd", monotonically_increasing_id())

df.show

val df2 = df.filter(col("flag")=== true)

df2.show

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, value: int ... 2 more fields]
+-----+-----+-----+----+
| name|value| flag|rowd|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|  one|    1| true|   0|
|  two|    2|false|   1|
|three|    3| true|   2|
| four|    4| true|   3|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [name: string, value: int ... 2 more fields]
+-----+-----+----+----+
| name|value|flag|rowd|
+-----+-----+----+----+
|  one|    1|true|   0|
|three|    3|true|   2|
| four|    4|true|   3|
+-----+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: I did not find any issue either with the above code

Comment: what is the equivalent of **monotonically_increasing_id()** in java

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.functions package is available in the Java API https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonicallyIncreasingId--

Answer (score 4):

I was recently working on a similar problem. Although `monotonically_increasing_id()` is very fast, it is not reliable and will not give you consecutive row numbers, only increasing unique integers.

Creating a windows partition and then using `row_number().over(some_windows_partition)` is extremely time consuming.

The best solution so far is using zipped with index and then converting the zipped file back to the original dataframe, with the new schema including the index column.

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType

new_schema = StructType(**original_dataframe**.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), False)])
zipped_rdd = **original_dataframe**.rdd.zipWithIndex()
indexed = (zipped_rdd.map(lambda ri: row_with_index(*list(ri[0]) + [ri[1]])).toDF(new_schema))
```

Where `original_dataframe` is the `dataframe` you have to add an index on and `row_with_index` is the new schema with the column index which you can write as

```
row_with_index = Row(
"calendar_date"
,"year_week_number"
,"year_period_number"
,"realization"
,"index"
)
```

Here, `calendar_date`, `year_week_number`, `year_period_number`, and `realization` were the columns of my original `dataframe`. You can replace the names with the names of your columns. The index is the new column name you had to add for the row numbers.

This process is largely more efficient and smoother when compared with `row_number().over(some_windows_partition)` method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To get around the shifting evaluation of monotonically_increasing_id(), you could try writing the dataframe to disk, and re-reading. Then the id column is now simply a data field that is being read, rather than dynamically calculated at some point in the pipeline. Although it's a pretty ugly solution, it worked when i did a quick test.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Created another identity column and used window function row_number

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{row_number}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1: DataFrame = df.withColumn("Id",lit(1))

df1
.select(
...,
row_number()
.over(Window
.partitionBy("Id"
.orderBy(col("...").desc))
)
.alias("Row_Nbr")
)
```

Comment: This would work, but would force the data into 1 partition removing the distribution and possibly lead to memory exceptions on large datasets

Answer (score 1):

In order to get better performance wrt Chris T solution, you may try to write to an apache ignite shared data frame instead of writing to disk.
https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/spark/shared-memory-layer.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use hash of concat of unique keys.

e.g: In python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, md5

unique_keys = ['event_datetime', 'ingesttime']
raw_df.withColumn('rowid', md5(concat(*unique_keys)))
```

The reasons:

- The new 'rowid' is derived from input data deterministically (vs. uuid, that is nondeterministic)
- It is easy to append new data. (vs. other ways: like monotonically_increasing_id() or row_number(), that would need to get the current max number .. )
- FYI https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/create-unique-record-key-for-table-linking/