# Dataframe change first n rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a dataframe and I want to add another column which for the first n rows is one value, and for the rest is the value in another column... something like this

```
frame.select("*")
.withColumn("newColumn", if(row number < 5) "hello, world" else col("someth_else"))
```

Comment: There are no row numbers in `Spark`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[If you are using spark >= 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe), you can use `monotonically_increasing_id()` to create a row index for the data frame, then use `when.otherwise` to conditionally create a new column based the condition (row_number):

```
val df = Seq(1,3,5,7,8).toDF("A")

df.withColumn("rn", monotonically_increasing_id()).
   withColumn("new", when($"rn" <= 2, lit("hello world")).otherwise($"A")).show

+---+---+-----------+
|  A| rn|        new|
+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  0|hello world|    
|  3|  1|hello world|
|  5|  2|hello world|
|  7|  3|          7|
|  8|  4|          8|
+---+---+-----------+
```