# How do I add an persistent column of row ids to Spark DataFrame - #2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Basically I want the same thing as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35705038/6699237). The accepted answer states that the issue is fixed with Spark 2.0 / Spark 2.1. I am using Spark 2.1.1.

However, I still experience the same (a similar) issue: I create an `ID` column using `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()` - expecting that this `ID` column would consistently identify a row during the SparkSession. However, it does not:

```
>>> import random
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F

>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

>>> data = []

>>> for i in range(10000):
...     data.append((i, i//20, random.random()))

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'GID', 'DAT1'])
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- GID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DAT1: double (nullable = true)

>>> df = (df
...       .repartition('GID')
...       .orderBy('GID', 'ID')
...       .withColumn('_ID', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
...       )

>>> df.where('ID = 100').show()
+---+---+------------------+----------+
| ID|GID|              DAT1|       _ID|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
|100|  5|0.5893680390376791|8589934635|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
>>> df.where('ID = 100').show()
+---+---+------------------+----------+
| ID|GID|              DAT1|       _ID|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
|100|  5|0.5893680390376791|8589934640|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
```

only after persisting the df, the result seems to be "stable":

```
>>> df = df.persist()
>>> df.where('ID = 100').show()
+---+---+------------------+----------+
| ID|GID|              DAT1|       _ID|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
|100|  5|0.5893680390376791|8589934638|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
>>> df.where('ID = 100').show()
+---+---+------------------+----------+
| ID|GID|              DAT1|       _ID|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
|100|  5|0.5893680390376791|8589934638|
+---+---+------------------+----------+
```

My questions thus:

- Am I missing something?
- Is this it, I mean, does `persist()` solve the issue for good or am I to expect more problems?