# add sequence number column in dataframe usnig scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

below is the logic to add sequence number column in dataframe. Its working as expected when I am reading data from delimited files. Today I have a new task to read the data from oracle table and add Sequence number and process further. I am facing issue with below logic to add sequence number in data frame when I read it from oracle table.

> oracleTableDF is my dataframe

```
   //creating Sequence no. logic for SeqNum
   val rowRDD = oracleTableDF.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq((((indexedRow._2.toLong+1)).toLong) +: indexedRow._1.toSeq)) 

  //creating StructType to add Seqnum in schema
        val newstructure = StructType(Array(StructField("SeqNum",LongType)).++(oracleTableDF.schema.fields))

  //creating new Data Frame with seqnum
  oracleTableDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, newstructure)
```

I am not able to locate the actual Issue. because the logic is working as expected in cluster when I read it from files. but facing some issue when I read it from oracle table. its working as expected in local mode also.

> below is the error :
>
> "ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, xxxx, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracleDataProcess$"

Comment: Is this `SeqNum` column like a row number?

Comment: Yes, I am adding row number to each records.

Comment: Yes, I need to add row number to each records.its working good for delimited files but sure when I tried for oracle table facing issue.

Comment: You can use Window function `row_number` instead of `monotonicallyIncreasingId` but you would have to work with a single partition to generate continuous row_number.

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is to add a column to your dataframe with an auto-increment integer value, you can use `monotonicallyIncreasingId` which is of `LongType`:

```
val oracleTableDF2 = oracleTableDF.withColumn("SeqNum", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

[UPDATE]

Note that `monotonicallyIncreasingId` is deprecated. `monotonically_increasing_id()` should be used instead.

Comment: As per suggestion on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe" its not a clear  function. and its does not take any parameters. I need to pass some parameters on this.

Comment: I believe issue [SPARK-14393](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14393) has already been resolved since `Spark 2.1`.  You're right that `monotonicallyIncreasingId` doesn't take parameter.

Comment: @LeoC, is there any way to get the values from 1?, now it is printing from 0.

Comment: @user4342532, monotonically_increasing_id() guarantees only generating `Long`s in a monotonically increasing fashion.  It may start from 0 or some `Long` integer.  If you want to have control in the id assignment, you should consider using [zipWithIndex](http://stdatalabs.blogspot.com/2016/09/assigning-row-number-in-spark-using.html) on a RDD, or `row_number()` Window function as illustrated in part of this [blog post](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/generate-unique-ids-for-each-rows-in-a-spark-dataframe/).

Comment: @LeoC, Thank you

Comment: @LeoC, when i use monotonicallyIncreasingId, its prints like 0,8589934592,17179869184,25769803776....

Comment: @user4342532, unfortunately monotonically_increasing_id() only guarantees the generated numbers are monotonically increasing.  There is no guarantee they will be consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can use is `monotonically_increasing_id()` to create a new column with an incremental id

```
val dataFrame = oracleTableDF.withColumn("incremental_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```