# Auto - Incrementing pyspark dataframe column values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate an additional column in a dataframe with auto incrementing values based on the global value.However all the rows are generated with the same value and the value is not incrementing.

Here is the code

```
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    if (rec == 0) : rec = 1 
    else : rec = rec + 1
    return int(rec)

rec=14
```

UDF

```
autoIncrementUDF = udf(autoIncrement,  IntegerType())


df1 = hiveContext.sql("select id,name,location,state,datetime,zipcode from demo.target")

df1.withColumn("id2", autoIncrementUDF()).show()
```

Here is the result df

```
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
| id|  name|location|     state|           datetime|zipcode|id2|
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
| 20|pankaj| Chennai| TamilNadu|2018-03-26 11:00:00|   NULL| 15|
| 10|geetha| Newyork|New Jersey|2018-03-27 10:00:00|   NULL| 15|
| 25| pawan| Chennai| TamilNadu|2018-03-27 11:25:00|   NULL| 15|
| 30|Manish| Gurgoan|   Gujarat|2018-03-27 11:00:00|   NULL| 15|
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
```

But i am expecting the below result

```
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
| id|  name|location|     state|           datetime|zipcode|id2|
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
| 20|pankaj| Chennai| TamilNadu|2018-03-26 11:00:00|   NULL| 15|
| 10|geetha| Newyork|New Jersey|2018-03-27 10:00:00|   NULL| 16|
| 25| pawan| Chennai| TamilNadu|2018-03-27 11:25:00|   NULL| 17|
| 30|Manish| Gurgoan|   Gujarat|2018-03-27 11:00:00|   NULL| 18|
+---+------+--------+----------+-------------------+-------+---+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since a `UDF` can be executed in different workers, a python `global` variable makes no sense as globals are bound to processes.

Answer (score 5):

Global variables are bounded to a python process. A `UDF` may be executed in parallel on different workers across some cluster, and should be deterministic.

You should use `monotonically_increasing_id()` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` module.

Check the [docs for more info](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html).

You should be careful because this function is dynamic and not sticky:

[How do I add an persistent column of row ids to Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Your first link is broken.