# monotonically_increasing_id is generating 2 different unique IDs for same record in spark 2.3.1?

Tags: apache-spark

I am creating a column in my dataframe using monotonically_increasing_id, over 2-3 transformation, for few of the records ID gets changed.
e.g

```
val newDf = df.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id()) 
newDf.show()

+---------+--------------------+-------+
| userId  | area    |  flag |rowId|
+---------+--------------------+-------+
|123      |[Blah1...|   true|    0|
|234      |[Blah2...|   true|    1|
|216      |[Blah3...|   true|    2|
|123      |[blah4...|  false|    3|
|345      |[Blah5...|   true|    4|
|677      |[Blah6...|  false|    5|
```

after some more transformation over newDf

```
...//val df1
...//val df2
...//val df3
...//val finalDf 

finalDf.show()

+---------+--------------------+-------+
| userId  | area    |  flag |rowId|
+---------+--------------------+-------+
|123      |[Blah1...|   true|    0|
|234      |[Blah2...|   true|    1|
|216      |[Blah3...|   true|    2|
|123      |[blah4...|  false|    6|
|345      |[Blah5...|   true|    7|
|677      |[Blah6...|  false|    8|
```

some of the rowiD got changed.

**Assuming that after generating a dataframe with monotonically_increasing_id, it  cache it to memory. What if it is evicted out of memory. Future action will try to regenerate the dataframe/(some of partition) again**

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This was an issue, before Spark 2.0.0. Since you mention your Spark version to 2.3.1, it is hard to help you without more information on the transformations you are performing on the data. Also, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe . The example data you pose in your question is eerily similar to the data in that question. Is this from some tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Here  I am giving a dummy dataframe, actual data size is in millions. So While performing groupby filters or similar more transformation, ID for some of the data is changing.

Comment: I know its not answering your question, but if you need incremental values for your rows, did you try zipWithIndex ?

Comment: Yes @TomaszKrol I tried but its not that performative as compared to monotonically_increasing_id