# Using monotonically_increasing_id won't give consecutively IDs (pyspark)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create an ID column for my pyspark dataframe, I have a column A that have repeated numbers, I want to take all the different values and assign an ID to each value

I have:

```
+----+
|   A|
+----+
|1001|
|1002|
|1003|
|1001|
|1003|
|1004|
|1001|
+----+
```

And I want:

```
+----+----+
|   A| new|
+----+----+
|1002|   1|
|1001|   2|
|1004|   3|
|1003|   4|
+----+----+
```

this is my code:

```
# Libraries
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Create pyspark dtaframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["A"] = [1001,1002,1003,1001,1003,1004,1001]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)

IDs = df.select("A").distinct()

from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id 
IDs = IDs.withColumn("new", monotonically_increasing_id() )
IDs.show()
```

And I get:

```
+----+-------------+
|   A|          new|
+----+-------------+
|1002| 188978561024|
|1001|1065151889408|
|1004|1511828488192|
|1003|1623497637888|
+----+-------------+
```

But It should be:

```
+----+----+
|   A| new|
+----+----+
|1002|   1|
|1001|   2|
|1004|   3|
|1003|   4|
+----+----+
```

Why I am getting that result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using monotonically\_increasing\_id() for assigning row number to pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209667/using-monotonically-increasing-id-for-assigning-row-number-to-pyspark-datafram)

Comment: Apparently it already works correctly, just not as you expected.

Comment: The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) is very clear on this: *The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but **not consecutive**.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark add sequential and deterministic index to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add an persistent column of row ids to Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

`monotonically_increasing_id` is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, **but not consecutive**. You can go with function `row_number()` instead of `monotonically_increasing_id` which will give your desire result more effectively.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, lit

// lit to keep everything in one partition
>>> w = Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy("A")
>>> df.show()
+----+
|   A|
+----+
|1001|
|1003|
|1001|
|1004|
|1005|
|1003|
|1005|
|1003|
|1006|
|1001|
|1002|
+----+

>>> df1 =  df.select("A").distinct().withColumn("ID", row_number().over(w))
>>> df1.show()
+----+---+
|   A| ID|
+----+---+
|1001|  1|
|1002|  2|
|1003|  3|
|1004|  4|
|1005|  5|
|1006|  6|
+----+---+
```

Comment: If you do not want to change order then you can use orderBy(lit(1)) instead of orderBy("A") in window which will give you exact your result.

Comment: Awesome! You made my day ;)