# data losing while reading a file of huge size in spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

```
val data = spark.read
    .text(filepath)
    .toDF("val")
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
val count = data.count()
```

This code works fine when I am reading a file contains upto 50k+ rows.. but when a file comes with rows more than that , this code starts losing data.when this code reads a file having 1 million+ rows , the final datframe count only gives 65k+ rows data.
I can't understand where the problem is happening in this code and what needs to change in this code so that it will ingest every data in the final dataframe.
p.s - highest file this code will ingest , having almost 14 million + rows , currently this code ingests only 2 million rows out of them.

Answer (score 1):

Seems related to [How do I add an persistent column of row ids to Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe#35706321)

i.e. avoid using `monotonically_increasing_id` and follow some of the suggestions from that thread.

Comment: Do you mean the value of `count` or the size of `finalDF`?