# How "stable" is monotonically_increasing_id() in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm looking for an inexpensive way to distinguish duplicates and/or uniquely identify rows. I've been looking at the Spark built-ins `monotonically_increasing_id()` and `uuid()`.

The problem with uuid() is that it does not retain its value and seems to be evaluated on the spot. For example

```sql
with uuids as (select uuid() as uuid)
select * from uuids join uuids
```

produces two different UUIDs.

If I use `monotonically_increasing_id()`, I get two identical values, but can I trust that to always work? In other words, if I have a CTE, where I have an `id` column generated by `monotonically_increasing_id()`, will any later rows derived from a row from that CTE have a consistent value of the `id` column within the same query?

In pseudo-SQL:

```sql
with /* ... */
  with_ids as (select monotonically_increasing_id() as id, * from /* ... */),
  /* ... */
  derived_a as (/* Somehow derived from with_ids */),
  derived_b as (/* Somehow derived from with_ids */)
 
select
  (a.id == b.id) as are_same,
  (a.id != b.id) as are_different
from derived_a as a
join derived_b as b
```

Will rows derived from the exact same rows of `with_ids` have `are_same == true`? Is it guaranteed that if the original rows were different, then `are_different == true`? The former is definitely false for `uuid()`.

**[Updated]** Another example, involving a join and group by:

```sql
with 
   with_ids as (
     select
       monotonically_increasing_id() as id
       ,*
     from table_a)
    
   joined as (
     select struct(a.*) as packed_a, a.id
     from with_ids as a
     left join table_b as b
     on /* whatever */
   )

select collect_set(packed_a) as should_be_singular
from joined
group by id
```

Is the row count in the above equal to the number of rows in `table_a` and is `should_be_singular` a single element array?

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#monotonically_increasing_id) for both functions state that they are non-deterministic, but don't really offer any details on when the functions are evaluated or how they should be used.

The issue seems to be mentioned in [SPARK-14241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14241) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe/35706321#35706321), but it's not clear if and under what conditions monotonically_increasing_id() is consistent within a single SQL statement.

Comment: are you using Delta tables?

Comment: Yes, I'm using delta tables.

Comment: FYI, I've discovered that neither monotonically_increasing_id() nor uuid() play well with AQE (on Spark 3.1 and 3.2) and can easily cause partition count to blow up to initialPartitionNum.

Answer (score 0):

from my past experience when working with row identifiers (uuid, row_number or monotonically_increasing_id) I `cache` the dataframe.

Then every subsequent calculation using the dataframe will have static row identifiers.

Comment: Yes, caching would work, although it's risky due to potential cache evictions. Unfortunately, the SQL syntax doesn't let you do that within a single statement, which is a requirement for me.

Comment: I have been burned by PARTIAL cache evictions where only a part of the dataframe was recalculated (and different ids created for the recalculated rows)

Comment: it's always possible to save the results on disk/s3 in those cases