# PySpark: Add a column to DataFrame when column is a list

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have read similar questions but couldn't find a solution to my specific problem.

I have a list

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

and a DataFrame

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    ['p1', 'a'],
    ['p2', 'b'],
    ['p3', 'c'],
]).toDF(('product', 'name'))
```

I would like to obtain a new DataFrame where the list `l` is added as a further column, namely

```
+-------+----+---------+
|product|name| new_col |
+-------+----+---------+
|     p1|   a|     1   |
|     p2|   b|     2   |
|     p3|   c|     3   |
+-------+----+---------+
```

Approaches with JOIN, where I was joining df with an

```
 sc.parallelize([[1], [2], [3]])
```

have failed. Approaches using `withColumn`, as in

```
new_df = df.withColumn('new_col', l)
```

have failed because the list is not a `Column` object.

Comment: I think this is a great question, because it shows a functionality that is seriously missing in Spark DataFrames API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from reading some interesting stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483498/append-a-column-to-data-frame-in-apache-spark-1-3), I've ascertained that you can't really just append a random / arbitrary column to a given `DataFrame` object. It appears what you want is more of a `zip` than a `join`. I looked around and found [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7460), which makes me think you won't be able to `zip` given that you have `DataFrame` rather than `RDD` objects.

The only way I've been able to solve your issue invovles leaving the world of `DataFrame` objects and returning to `RDD` objects. I've also needed to create an index for the purpose of the join, which may or may not work with your use case.

```
l = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
index = sc.parallelize(range(0, l.count()))
z = index.zip(l)

rdd = sc.parallelize([['p1', 'a'], ['p2', 'b'], ['p3', 'c']])
rdd_index = index.zip(rdd)

# just in case!
assert(rdd.count() == l.count())
# perform an inner join on the index we generated above, then map it to look pretty.
new_rdd = rdd_index.join(z).map(lambda (x, y): [y[0][0], y[0][1], y[1]])
new_df = new_rdd.toDF(["product", 'name', 'new_col'])
```

When I run `new_df.show()`, I get:

```
+-------+----+-------+
|product|name|new_col|
+-------+----+-------+
|     p1|   a|      1|
|     p2|   b|      2|
|     p3|   c|      3|
+-------+----+-------+
```

---

Sidenote: I'm really surprised this didn't work. Looks like an outer join?

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
new_row = Row("new_col_name")
l_as_df = l.map(new_row).toDF()
new_df = df.join(l_as_df)
```

When I run `new_df.show()`, I get:

```
+-------+----+------------+
|product|name|new_col_name|
+-------+----+------------+
|     p1|   a|           1|
|     p1|   a|           2|
|     p1|   a|           3|
|     p2|   b|           1|
|     p3|   c|           1|
|     p2|   b|           2|
|     p2|   b|           3|
|     p3|   c|           2|
|     p3|   c|           3|
+-------+----+------------+
```

Comment: Note that you can transform a DataFrame into an RDD using df.rdd directly, for example on my df in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the `product` column is unique then consider the following approach:

original dataframe:

```
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    ['p1', 'a'],
    ['p2', 'b'],
    ['p3', 'c'],
]).toDF(('product', 'name'))

df.show()

+-------+----+
|product|name|
+-------+----+
|     p1|   a|
|     p2|   b|
|     p3|   c|
+-------+----+
```

new column (and new index column):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
indx = ['p1','p2','p3']
```

create a new dataframe from the list above (with an index):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
myschema= StructType([ StructField("indx", StringType(), True),
                       StructField("newCol", IntegerType(), True)                       
                     ])
df1=spark.createDataFrame(zip(indx,lst),schema = myschema)
df1.show()
+----+------+
|indx|newCol|
+----+------+
|  p1|     1|
|  p2|     2|
|  p3|     3|
+----+------+
```

join this to the original dataframe, using the index created:

```
dfnew = df.join(df1, df.product == df1.indx,how='left')\
          .drop(df1.indx)\
          .sort("product")
```

to get:

```
dfnew.show()

+-------+----+------+
|product|name|newCol|
+-------+----+------+
|     p1|   a|     1|
|     p2|   b|     2|
|     p3|   c|     3|
+-------+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable via RDDs.

1 Convert dataframes to indexed rdds:

```
df_rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda row: (row[1], (row[0][0], row[0][1])))
l_rdd = sc.parallelize(l).zipWithIndex().map(lambda row: (row[1], row[0]))
```

2 Join two RDDs on index, drop index and rearrange elements:

```
res_rdd = df_rdd.join(l_rdd).map(lambda row: [row[1][0][0], row[1][0][1], row[1][1]])
```

3 Convert result to Dataframe:

```
res_df = res_rdd.toDF(['product', 'name', 'new_col'])
res_df.show()

+-------+----+-------+
|product|name|new_col|
+-------+----+-------+
|     p1|   a|      1|
|     p2|   b|      2|
|     p3|   c|      3|
+-------+----+-------+
```