# PySpark add new column to dataframe with new list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Based on previous questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222872/add-list-as-column-to-dataframe-in-pyspark), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark). Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], 
     ("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

And I want to add new column `x4` but I have value in a list of Python instead to add to the new column e.g. `x4_ls = [35.0, 32.0]`. Is there a best way to add new column to the Spark dataframe? (**note** that I use Spark 2.1)

Output should be something like:

```
## +---+---+-----+----+
## | x1| x2|   x3|  x4|
## +---+---+-----+----+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|35.0|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|32.0|
## +---+---+-----+----+
```

I can also transform my list to dataframe `df_x4 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(**{'x4': x}) for x in x4_ls])` (but I don't how to concatenate dataframe together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gaurav Dhama for a great answer! I made changes a little with his solution. Here is my solution which join two dataframe together on added new column `row_num`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def flatten_row(r):
    r_ =  r.features.asDict()
    r_.update({'row_num': r.row_num})
    return Row(**r_)

def add_row_num(df):
    df_row_num = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF(['features', 'row_num'])
    df_out = df_row_num.rdd.map(lambda x : flatten_row(x)).toDF()
    return df_out

df = add_row_num(df)
df_x4 = add_row_num(df_x4)
df_concat = df.join(df_x4, on='row_num').drop('row_num')
```

Comment: Seems like there is no easy way to concatenate dataframe or add values to dataframe right now.

Answer (score 0):

We can concatenate on the basis of rownumbers as follows. Suppose we have two dataframes df and df_x4 :

```
def addrownum(df):
    dff = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF(['features','rownum'])
    odf = dff.map(lambda x : tuple(x.features)+tuple([x.rownum])).toDF(df.columns+['rownum'])
    return odf

df1 = addrownum(df)
df2 = addrownum(df_x4)

outputdf = df1.join(df2,df1.rownum==df2.rownum).drop(df1.rownum).drop(df2.rownum)

## outputdf
## +---+---+-----+----+
## | x1| x2|   x3|  x4|
## +---+---+-----+----+
## |  1|  a| 23.0|35.0|
## |  3|  B|-23.0|32.0|
## +---+---+-----+----+
```

outputdf is your required output dataframe