# Spark (Java) - Adding a single average as a new column

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, and I'd like to add a new column to the second one. This new column should be the average of a column from the first dataframe. Something like this:

```
df1                  df2                   df2
userid count value   userid count          userid count value
11     2     5       10     1              10     1     5
22     3     4       20     1     ======>  20     1     5
33     5     6       30     1              30     1     5
```

I'm trying

```
df2 = df2.withColumn("value", avg(df1.col("value")));
```

which is not working. How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: you need to join both dataframes before you can do any operation. Spark doesn't know how to relate df1 to df2.

Comment: Oh. That seems tedious, since in the end I'd want to `.unionAll()` them into a single df, but I can't do that until they have the same no of columns...

Comment: I think the problem you try to solve is related with http://stackoverflow.com/a/29950853/702002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to [Append a column to Data Frame in Apache Spark 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483498/append-a-column-to-data-frame-in-apache-spark-1-3)

withColum() should have a column related to the DateFrame, so you can make a transformation:

- cal the avg value
- when adding a new column, set the original value as 0, and then add the avg value

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  val avgValue = df1.select(avg(df1("value"))).collect()(0).getDouble(0)
  df2 = df2.withColumn("value", rand() * 0 + avgValue)
  ```

Comment: Ah! `rand() * 0 + avgValue` is really clever to genereate a column of data from a single value. Thanks! I'll test it on Monday, but I'll trust you on this and accept your answer ;)