# Adding StringType column to existing Spark DataFrame and then applying default values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Scala 2.10 here using Spark 1.6.2. I have a *similar* (but not the same) question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483498/append-a-column-to-data-frame-in-apache-spark-1-3), however, the accepted answer is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and assumes a certain amount of "upfront knowledge" about Spark; and therefore I can't reproduce it or make sense of it. **More importantly**, that question is also just limited to adding a new column to an existing dataframe, whereas I need to add a column *as well as* a value for all existing rows in the dataframe.

---

So I want to add a column to an existing Spark DataFrame, and then apply an initial ('default') value for that new column to all rows.

```
val json : String = """{ "x": true, "y": "not true" }"""
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(json))
val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

jsonDF.show()
```

When I run that I get this following as output (via `.show()`):

```
+----+--------+
|   x|       y|
+----+--------+
|true|not true|
+----+--------+
```

Now I want to add a new field to `jsonDF`, after it's created and without modifying the `json` string, such that the resultant DF would look like this:

```
+----+--------+----+
|   x|       y|   z|
+----+--------+----+
|true|not true| red|
+----+--------+----+
```

Meaning, I want to add a new "`z`" column to the DF, of type `StringType`, and then default all rows to contain a `z`-value of `"red"`.

From that other question I have pieced the following pseudo-code together:

```
val json : String = """{ "x": true, "y": "not true" }"""
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(json))
val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

//jsonDF.show()

val newDF = jsonDF.withColumn("z", jsonDF("col") + 1)

newDF.show()
```

But when I run this, I get a compiler error on that `.withColumn(...)` method:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "col" among (x, y);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.apply(DataFrame.scala:652)
```

I also don't see any API methods that would allow me to set `"red"` as the default value. Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `lit` function. First you have to import it

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
```

and use it as shown below

```
jsonDF.withColumn("z", lit("red"))
```

Type of the column will be inferred automatically.